# How to list fields and values in a QSqlRecord?

Tags: database, qt

Debugging database operations is easier when I can somehow easily get all the fields and values that exist in a `QSqlRecord`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me quite some time to figure out how to do this from Qt docs, though it is rather simple in the end.

```
// QSqlRecord record;
for(int i=0;i<record.count();i++){
    QSqlField field=record.field(i);
    qDebug()<<field.name()<<field.value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Qt 6.2.4    
QSqlRecord qpr = db->record("tablename");
qDebug() << qpr;
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on how why why this works?